# Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 .NET 4.6.2 Windows 10 Anniversary Edition

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.6.2

I recently updated my Windows 10 to the anniversary edition which includes the .NET v4.6.2 Framework. When I try to load a project targeting the v4.6.2 framework in Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3, VS tells me v4.6.2 is "not installed on this machine". When I try to download and install v4.6.2, the installer tells me v4.6.2 or higher is already installed on this machine. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Install .NET 4.6.2 Developer pack:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321

Comment: That did the trick. Do you want to add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to install the [.NET 4.6.2 Developer pack](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321).

Comment: Try installing the English version. I first installed the Czech version, installer file name ends with "-CSY.exe", 12 MB. It didn't work. I tried the English installer then, name ends by "-ENU.exe", 83 MB and that works.